# JQuery tooltip with blinking safari

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm having a nightmare making a tooltip, after a couple of hours spent on reviewing my code and checking some plugin and I decided to ask for some help before I go crazy.

Basically my tooltip runs perfectly in all browsers with one exception; Safari. My problem is when I pass over any images, the browser starts blinking with white colour, I havent' found any solution but looks like my problem is the tooltip script.

I have an example:

JS

```
this.imagePreview = function()
{   
    var xOffset = 10;
    var yOffset = 30;

    $('#Images a').hover(function(e)
    {
        var tooltipName = $(this).attr('rel');

        this.t = this.title;
        this.title = "";    
        var c = (this.t != "") ? "<br/>" + this.t : "";

        $("body").append("<p id='tooltip' class='imageToolTip'><img src='" + BASE + "/img/template/Images/tooltip" + tooltipName + ".png' />"+ c +"</p>");  

        $("#tooltip")
        .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
        .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
        .fadeIn("fast");                        
    },
    function(){
        this.title = this.t;    
        $("#tooltip").remove();
    });

    $('#Images a').mousemove(function(e)
    {
        $("#tooltip")
            .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
            .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
    });

};
```

CSS

```
.imageToolTip {position: absolute; z-index: 9999; margin-left: -120px; margin-top: 27px;}
```

Many thanks for all your help.

Comment: just a quick thought, because it often solves such issues: have you tried calling `stop()` before `fadeIn`?

Comment: nevermind, just realized that you create the tooltip dom element just a few lines before fading in.

Comment: I have but didnt work. also when i left 2 remove just blink once, that very weird. Cheers

Comment: twitter's bootstrap css/js framework implements different form of tooltips, which work perfectly in all browsers, maybe take a peak at their code to get some ideas to improve yours? [http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#twipsy](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#twipsy)

Comment: I'll have a look it thanks Marian.

Comment: I once fixed a similar problem for someone by only declaring either the xOffset or yOffset instead of both, unsure whether this would work for you.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you are using on hover. On hover is a constant callback which triggers for every pixel you move, just like resizewindow would.

You'd be best off splitting you function up into "mouseenter" and "mouseleave".
Also, this way of using callbacks is getting outdated. The new method (which is quite handy) is to use `$('#id').on("mouseenter", function(){});`

Your mousemove triggers should also be used with care. It might be smart to combine a boolean with the mouseenter and leave functions.

For the idea in steps:
first create `var entered = false;`
1: mouse enters the area
2: Do whatever you want to do, and then say `"entered = true;"`
3: Now that you've done this, surround your onhover function (or mouseenter, or on mouse move, or any function that would make something happen) with `if(!entered){//do your thing}`
4: now you have to calculate if the person is still within your offsets. If not: `entered = false;`

Because they left the area, the effect we put in the `if(!entered)` statements can trigger again, but only once this time.